# XPath - Selecting preceding and following sibling of a specific node in a single query

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm currently working with Open Street Maps data and I'm trying to select the preceding and following sibling of a specific node.

My queries currently look like this :

```
/osm/way/nd[@ref=203936110]/following-sibling::nd[1]
/osm/way/nd[@ref=203936110]/preceding-sibling::nd[1]
```

These queries work as expected but I'd like to merge them into a single query. I did found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388923/combining-the-use-of-preceding-and-following-sibling-in-the-same-xpath-query) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027814/xpath-expression-to-select-self-preceding-and-following-nodes) mentioning that this is possible but for some reason I haven't been able to find the right syntax to make it work.

This query, for example, is invalid :

```
/osm/way/nd[@ref=203936110]/(following-sibling::nd[1] or preceding-sibling::nd[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using lxml (which currently only [supports XPath version 1.0](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)), you have to spell out each XPath entirely, and join them with `|`:

```
'''/osm/way/nd[@ref=203936110]/following-sibling::nd[1] 
   | /osm/way/nd[@ref=203936110]/preceding-sibling::nd[1]'''
```

For example,

```
import lxml.etree as ET
content = '''\
<record>
    <nd>First</nd>
    <nd>Second</nd>
    <nd ref="203936110"></nd>
    <nd>Third</nd>
    <nd>Fourth</nd>    
</record>'''
root = ET.fromstring(content)

for elt in root.xpath('''
    //nd[@ref="203936110"]/following-sibling::nd[1]
    |
    //nd[@ref="203936110"]/preceding-sibling::nd[1]'''):

    print(elt.text)
```

yields

```
Second
Third
```

Comment: You could also "or" them in a predicate: '//nd[following-sibling::nd[1][@ref="203936110"] or preceding-sibling::nd[1][@ref="203936110"]]'

But I think unioning the nodesets is probably a better approach.

Comment: @brjaga: That would match `nd`s that *have* a following-sibling or preceding-sibling -- not the siblings themselves.

Comment: The nodes we're looking for are `nd`s (`following-sibling::nd[1]`). The node found by `//nd[@ref="blah"]/following-sibling::nd[1]` is the same one found by `//nd[preceding-sibling::nd[1][@ref="blah"]]` (you can check it with the example above). In general, I do think the unioning option is more elegant, but I've run into certain situations where I can only get an axis to work inside a predicate.

Comment: @brjaga: Oops, I mispoke -- you are correct. That's an interesting alternative.